# Convergence radius of $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ \left\lfloor \sqrt { n } \right\rfloor } }{ n } } { x }^{ n }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find the radius of the seria

> $$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ \left\lfloor \sqrt { n }  \right\rfloor  } }{ n }  } { x }^{ n }$$

where, $\left\lfloor \sqrt { n}  \right\rfloor $ is floor function.I haven't got any idea.Any help will be appriciated

Comment: The convergence radius is unaffected by the funny power of $-1$.  The endpoints could be, but that does not seem to be asked about.

Comment: That is not a power series because the coefficients depend on $x.$ You can still talk about the values for which this series converges, but "radius of convergence" is not really the right term here. Also, what does $\sqrt x$ mean if $x$ is negative?

Comment: is there $\\ \\ \sqrt { n } $ or $\\ \\ \sqrt { x } $?,becuase i posted aswer as $\\ \\ \sqrt { n } $

Comment: It was typo, sorry $sqrt(n)$

Comment: @AndréNicolas you could say that it is unaffected by the whole $\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}}{n}$ term

Comment: @user1952009: Indeed we could. But I just wanted to reduce the problem to one that OP already knew how to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Cauchy root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test),$$\frac { 1 }{ R } =\overline { \underset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ lim }  } \sqrt [ n ]{ \left| \frac { { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ \left\lfloor \sqrt { n }  \right\rfloor  } }{ n }  \right|  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt [ n ]{ n }  } =1 } $$,so 
$$\left| x \right| <1$$